# question involving upperbound and lowerbound

Tags: c++

Find position of the last and first occurrence of a given number in a sorted array. If number does not exist then print lower and upper bound as -1.
I have written the code as follows but I cannot pass all the test cases. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int n,num,q,find;
    cin>>n;
    v.reserve(n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>num;
        v.push_back(num);
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    cin>>q;

    while(q--){
        cin>>find;
        auto lb=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),find);
        auto ub=upper_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),find);

        if(lb==v.end() || v.empty()){
            cout<<-1<<" "<<-1<<endl;
        }

        else{
            cout<<lb-v.begin()<<" "<<ub-v.begin()-1<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an example test case which doesn't pass. Will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: If the array is sorted, why do you sort it again?

Comment: "Returns an iterator pointing to the **first** element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found." Does that answer your question?

Comment: yeah my mistake its already sorted but it doesn't change anything right

Comment: nope @Swift-FridayPie

Comment: Where is the check for "If number does not exist" requirement?

Comment: @Evg if the number doesnot exist lower bound will point to v.end() and print -1 -1

Comment: That's wrong. Consider `1 3 5` and target value `4`. `lower_bound` will return `5`, not `end()`.

Comment: yeah, for this task range-based for loop or find_if are more apt.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, if the range is sorted, [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) + a few trivial checks will do the job.

Comment: Thank for clarification @Evg.I just pust count(v.begin(),v.find(),find) to check if the number exists and then print -1 -1.It's all good now

Comment: Don't use `count`, it turns O(log N) algorithm into O(N) one. Simply check `lb !=  v.end() && *lb == find`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound(first, last, value)` doesn't find the element equal to `value`, it finds the [lower bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (the first element that is not less than `value`), as its name suggests. For example, for the range `1 3 5` and the target value `2`, it will return the iterator that points at `3`.

To check that the element exists in an array, you can write

```
auto pos = std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
if (pos != last && *pos == value)
    // ...
```

It should also be noted that two calls to `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` can be replaced with a single call to [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).